# Get YouTube title with video ID in Android using API 3.0

Tags: php, android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I've been trying some ways, and searching for the whole day. The shortest way I can find is placing the videoID in a YouTube player, and then getting its title. But I'm sure there's a shorter/cleaner way than that.

I also accept using PHP instead of the API, but I don't really know how because methods changed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with PHP. I still want to know how to do this with API 3.0 but this looks easier. The method just gets a string, analyzes it (gets the ID) and then sends it to an asynktask that makes a connection with the PHP file and retrieves the string to an EditText.

You don't really need the PHP file, because you can get this from YouTube itself. What you will always need is the YouTube API Key.

### This is the Java Method:

```
private void getVideoTitle(String t) {
    String id = "---";
    int i = 0;
    if (t.length() == 11) {
        id = t;
    }
    else {
        i = t.toLowerCase().indexOf("https://youtu.be/".toLowerCase());
        if (i > -1) {
            id = t.substring(i + 17, i + 28);
        }
        else {
            i = t.toLowerCase().indexOf("v=".toLowerCase());
            if (i > -1) {
                id = t.substring(i + 2, i + 13);
            }
        }
    }

    class YTF extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            edtTitle.setText(s);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... p) {
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("personal php file that gets title from id?id=" + p[0]);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                return br.readLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    if(id.length()>3){
        YTF ytf = new YTF();
        ytf.execute(id);
    }
    else{
        Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView(), "Not a YT Link", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).setAction("YT", null).show();
    }
}
```

### This is the PHP file:

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=".$_GET['id']."&key=1234567890&fields=items(id,snippet(title),statistics)&part=snippet,statistics");
    $json = json_decode($data, true);
    $videoTitle = $json['items'][0]['snippet']['title'];
    if(empty($videoTitle)){echo "Uops.";}else{echo $videoTitle;}
?>
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started There are various examples shown in there for this.

```
URL: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&key=YOUR_API_KEY
     &part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status

Description: This example retrieves a video resource and identifies several
             resource parts that should be included in the API response.

API response:

{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"UCBpFjp2h75_b92t44sqraUcyu0/sDAlsG9NGKfr6v5AlPZKSEZdtqA\"",
 "videos": [
  {
   "id": "7lCDEYXw3mM",
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"UCBpFjp2h75_b92t44sqraUcyu0/iYynQR8AtacsFUwWmrVaw4Smb_Q\"",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2012-06-20T22:45:24.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
    "title": "Google I/O 101: Q&A On Using Google APIs",
    "description": "Antonio Fuentes speaks to us and takes questions on working with Google APIs and OAuth 2.0.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7lCDEYXw3mM/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "categoryId": "28"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT15M51S",
    "aspectRatio": "RATIO_16_9"
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "3057",
    "likeCount": "25",
    "dislikeCount": "0",
    "favoriteCount": "17",
    "commentCount": "12"
   },
   "status": {
    "uploadStatus": "STATUS_PROCESSED",
    "privacyStatus": "PRIVACY_PUBLIC"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```